# How to find the equation of a parabola given the turning points and 1 of the roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that the turning point of this parabola is (-2,-4) and 1 of the roots is (1,0), please find the equation of this parabola. I started off by substituting the given numbers into the turning point form. $0=a(x+2)^2-4$ but i do not know where to put the roots in and form an equation.Please help thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

The equation is

$$y=a(x+2)^2-4$$

Now, use the property that it passes through $(1,0)$  to solve for $a$.

Comment: Since the vertex is $(-2, -4)$, the equation should have the form $y = a(x + 2)^2 - 4$.

Comment: oops, you are right, thanks.